# Failed to start LSB: Virtualbox Linux kernel module

Tags: boot, kernel

When I try to boot Ubuntu my system shows this.. i have two operating systems windows 10-ubuntu 15.10...when i try to boot ubuntu it appears the ubuntu logo and after that this error..so i cannot log in or open up my terminal..
[image]

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Post the results of `sudo systemctl status virtualbox.service` in your question

Comment: how to run this?

Comment: open a terminal with `ctrl + alt + t` then type in `sudo systemctl status virtualbox.service` and after __copy from terminal by using mouse, drag over the text in terminal and right click to copy__

Comment: I cannot open up my terminal..i cannot gei into my os..i am stuck in this screen

Comment: Please put more detail into your question so you can get better help. Include the computer specs, OS version etc

Comment: I will explain..to begin with i have two operating systems windows 10-ubuntu 15.10...when i try to bbot ubuntu it appears the ubuntu logo and after that this error..so i cannot log in or open up my terminal..

Comment: Please put that in your post, use the __edit button__ and add it there.

Comment: Are you presented with a login terminal at the end of the error shown here.

Comment: I am sorry..i do not understand exactly the question.

Comment: When these errors on your screen start appearing they will eventually come to a stop, at that point do you see a blinking cursor at the end that you can sign into ? Or better add the image of the last line in the errors shown in your post.

Comment: They eventually come to a stop but i cannot write anything or something like that

Comment: How did you install __virtualbox__ ? Downloaded from __Oracle__ or from __Ubuntu deb__ pacakges.

Comment: I use this command..    sudo apt-get install virtualbox

Comment: Is there any way to delete virtualbox?

Comment: From ubuntu deb packages

Comment: When you installed it did it install correctly?

Comment: Yes..it does not show any error

Comment: Now I am going to add an answer , the first is to get you to grub, and the second is to get rid of virtualbox when you have access. Give me a minute to put this together.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS. That should fix it.

To enter your BIOS, turn on your computer, and watch the BIOS flash screen and it'll usually tell you what key to touch to enter the BIOS (usually a function key). Once in the BIOS settings, depending on your BIOS, you might see a security section or tab. Find the secure boot option and turn it off, save your changes, and reboot the computer.

**Update #1:**

To perform a file system check...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- *you can ignore errors about the time/date/superblock*
- repeat the fsck command if there were other errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #2:**

To remove virtualbox...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:
- `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
- `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-qt`
- `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox`
- `reboot`

**Update #3:**

To try and fix failed updates...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:
- `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get install -f`
- `reboot`

**Update #4:**

After many failed attempts to fix the problems, you're going to have to reinstall Ubuntu. I don't think that the virtualbox install caused this problem. There must have been something wrong before, even if you didn't know it. I'd always recommend that you have **good Windows and Ubuntu backups**, just in case anything goes wrong. You'll need a Ubuntu 15.10 DVD/USB, choose **reinstall** so that it reinstalls into the same place as is currently used, but make sure to **uncheck format partition** so it'll keep your /home directory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51083/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-failed-to-start-lsb-virtualbox-linux-kernel-mo).

Comment: Since you obviously missed it, I've erasified the comments that *were* here.  Go continue getting help in the chat room, as the comment from @Seth indicated now exists.

Comment: @ThomasWard Seth moved the extended comments to chat. I guess he forgot to "erasify" the comments here. Thanks for doing that. I don't know how to do either.